# Prepare "against" versus "for"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Is there a difference in the meanings of ***to prepare for*** and ***to prepare against*** something?

To my ears, ***to prepare against*** sounds as though one is expecting something challenging or negative, whereas ***to prepare for*** sounds more neutral. But, I am not so sure.

Comment: Could you give a couple of concrete examples?

Comment: "Thus, they were able to prepare themselves not only against immediate threats..."

Comment: I agree with the analysis in the question.

Comment: _Prepare against_ sounds odd to me, and when I googled it, though several suggested searches such as _prepare against flooding_ came up, presumably because people had searched for them, the actual results all read _prepare for_. I don't think _prepare against_ is standard English.